# Who are the "Heirs of the Blade"?

Tags: books, shadows-of-the-apt

The seventh (and latest) book of the [Shadows of the Apt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Apt) series by Adrian Tchaikovsky is titled "Heirs of the Blade". However the only one I would really call a heir of the blade is

> Tynisa.

So who are the others that can be called a "Heir of the Blade"?

Comment: +1 I really need to get caught up on this series.

Answer (score 4):

I happen to know Adrian Czajkowski (look at me name dropping horribly - if only I had his talent too) so I asked him.  He says that

> the death of Tisamon (the "blade" of the title) is obviously
>  what's driving Tynisa, but the circumstances of that death are also what has
>  created both Che and Seda in their current Inapt incarnations. All three are
>  the heirs of his legacy.